# Dynamic checkbox not well updated if ther's no click event

Tags: angular, forms

I have this supplier filter dynamic checkbox form.

```
<form  (submit)="submit(form.value)">
        <label  class="form-check" *ngFor="let supplier of suppliers;">

          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                 (change)="filter(supplier.label, $event.target.checked)"
                 [checked]="(filters|json).indexOf((supplier.label).id) >= 0"
          >
          <span class="form-check-label">
                <span class="float-right badge badge-light round">{{supplier.count}}</span>
                  {{(supplier.label).name}}
              </span>
        </label>
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary">Apply</button>{{form.value|json}} <-- the form.value is not updated if filters is updated, even the input is unchecked-->
</form>
```

I have two components and I'm working with an `@Input (): filters` decorator to receive kind of selected checkboxes from the first component.
This is my Supplier Filter Compononent:

```
export class SupplierFilterComponent {

    form: FormGroup;
    suppliersFormArray: FormArray;
    @Input() suppliers: Aggregation[];
    @Input() filters: Filter[];
    @Output() eventEmitterFilter = new EventEmitter<number>();

    constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {console.log(this.filters);
        this.form = formBuilder.group({
            'suppliers': formBuilder.array([])
        });
    }

    filter($label: string, isChecked: boolean) {
        const supplier = JSON.parse($label);

        this.suppliersFormArray = <FormArray>this.form.controls.suppliers;

        if (isChecked) {
            this.suppliersFormArray.push(new FormControl(supplier));
        } else {
            const index = this.suppliersFormArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value.id === supplier.id);
            this.suppliersFormArray.removeAt(index);
        }
    }

    submit($event) {
        this.eventEmitterFilter.emit($event.suppliers);
    }
}
```

Normally, if the filter's input is updated, the checkbox form values will be updated. Weather an input is checked or unchecked(its dependence on the `@Input (): filters` value).

Normally if `filters` change this part `(change)="filter(..` will be triggered. But unfortunately `(change)` is not triggered.
I dont know why the `form.value` is not updated for each update on the `@Input (): filters` value. (It's only updated only if I click)
As you see ther's only **at** checked because `this.filters` contain only **at**, but unfortenly the **form.value** contain another element "aspernatur".
[image]

I dont understand why the input is unchecked but the **form.value** is not updated. Can someone help me to figure out how to update form. value if `filters` value change.

Comment: Would it be possible to build a simple example stackblitz.com that demonstrates your issue? That may make it easier for us to help.

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply, i didnt find a way to deploy the project to Stackblitz. Any way I give you some usefull links: http://165.227.20.253:4200/articles you can login then take a look
I found a slotuion for my problem but it's not clean because i'm removing all form control from builder then re pushing new ones: takes a look to the fix i died under `ngChanges()` https://github.com/ahmed-bhs/angular6-demo/blob/master/src/app/article/supplier-filter/supplier-filter.component.ts

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest deploying your project ... rather using Stackblitz to build an example of the issue you are having. That way we could look at just the issue without needing to understand all of your code.